# How do I connect to a Serverless Aurora Mysql Database outside of VPC using Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm having allot of trouble connecting to Aurora Serverless. I run through the wizard, put the DB in public subnets with a security group to allow traffic on `3306`, there are no ACLs blocking traffic, and I can't connect!

I try launching a Mysql t2.rds instance with the same security groups, same subnets, and can connect no problem! Is there anything funky you have to do with an Aurora Serverless Database? I am now going to try launching an ec2 instance ssh in and see if I can connect from that.

Extra info I do have the database scaling to 0 ACU when inactive, but even when I try setting the capacity for a time period and connect it does not work. I have literarily no idea why this is not working, username/pword correct, tried resetting them, is there anything out of the normal troubleshooting realm which you need do?